# Playing large videos (FullHD+) with vlcj using DirectMediaPlayer

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I have to play rather large Videos, in some cases UHD (4000x2000), in a Java/OpenGL Application. I now settled in VLCJ to do this (Could not get GStreamer to decode fast enough).
VLC itself plays the video just fine as does VLCJ when using a normal embedded player.

When I'm using the directplayer larger videos start to play and stop after a few frames or just don't start at all (display() is still called, but always with the same frame!). For me that starts somewhere between HDReady (1280x720 still plays fine) and FullHD(1920x1080). This seems not dependend on the performance of the PC. I testet this on an 5 year old laptop and on a highend machine with exactly the same results.
Any ideas if I am doing something wrong or if VLCJ DirectPlayer just can't handle larger videos?

I am using VLC 2.0.0 (also tried 2.0.3 and 2.0.4) with the latest VLCJ from github.

I have a log online on : http://pastebin.com/UeyMrVmW

I attatch a simple example how I set up the direct player which recreates the problem.

```
public class VLCTestPlayer implements RenderCallback, BufferFormatCallback {

protected MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;

protected DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            VLCTestPlayer testplayer = new VLCTestPlayer(args);
        }
    });
}

private VLCTestPlayer(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");

    mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--no-video-title-show", "--verbose=3");

    mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newDirectMediaPlayer(this, this);

    String videoFile = "myVideo.mp4";
    boolean started = mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(videoFile);

    if (started)
        mediaPlayer.play();
    System.out.println("Video started: " + started + " from: " + videoFile);

    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setSize(1050, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
    sourceWidth = sourceWidth / 1;
    sourceHeight = sourceHeight / 1;
    System.out.println("Got VideoFormat: " + sourceWidth + "x"
            + sourceHeight);
    BufferFormat format = new BufferFormat("RGBA", sourceWidth,
            sourceHeight, new int[] { sourceWidth * 4 },
            new int[] { sourceHeight });

    return format;
}

@Override
public void display(DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer, Memory[] nativeBuffers,
        BufferFormat bufferFormat) {

    ByteBuffer buffer = nativeBuffers[0].getByteBuffer(0,
            (int) bufferFormat.getWidth() * (int) bufferFormat.getHeight()
                    * 4);
    int pos = 4 * ((int) bufferFormat.getWidth()
            * (int) bufferFormat.getHeight() / 2 + (int) bufferFormat
            .getWidth() / 2) + 700;
    System.out.println("Got VideoFrame: " + buffer.get(pos) + ":"
            + buffer.get(pos + 1) + ":" + buffer.get(pos + 2) + ":"
            + buffer.get(pos + 3));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is almost definitely a performance issue despite your tests - from my experience playing HD video with a direct player even on modern systems in the way you're doing there won't work, without hardware acceleration it just won't cope. As a rough guide, my 6 month old i5 desktop barely manages 720p video. (As a side note, the println statements you have in there definitely won't help matters, when done that many times a second they may take up more time than you think.)

However, the saving grace is that you should be able to get this to work using JavaFX and the hardware accelerated classes it provides - see [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2434712) for details.